# Docker Kafka and Spring Boot - Can't connect on Broker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka

I'm trying to run a Spring Boot application that communicates with Kafka using Docker Compose. However, when I bring it up, it can't connect to the broker.

I only see this message in a loop:

```
INFO 1 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Node -1 disconnected.
WARN 1 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-1] Connection to node -1 
(localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

**My docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3'

networks:
    kafka-net:
        name: kafka-net
        driver: bridge

services:

    zookeeper:
        image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
        environment:
            ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
        networks:
            - kafka-net
        ports:
            - 22181:2181

    kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
        environment:
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 127.0.0.1
            KAFKA_LISTENERS: DOCKER_INTERNAL://:29092,DOCKER_EXTERNAL://:9092
            KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka:29092,DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
            KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
            KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: DOCKER_INTERNAL
            KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
            KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
            KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
            KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: true
        networks:
            - kafka-net
        depends_on:
            - zookeeper
        ports:
            - 9092:9092

    common-kafka:
        build:
            context: ./common-kafka
        environment:
            KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092
        networks:
            - kafka-net
        depends_on:
            - kafka
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
```

**My application.properties:**

```
server.port=8081

kafka.bootstrap-servers=127.0.0.1:9092
kafka.producer.retries=5

kafka.transfer.topic=TRANSFER
kafka.transfer.topic.dlt=TRANSFER-dlt

kafka.transfer.log.group=log_transfer_group
kafka.transfer.email.group=send_email_transfer_group
```

**My Config Classes:**

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigKafkaConsumer {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, TransferNotification> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TransferNotification> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, TransferNotification> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    private Map<String,Object> properties() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "br.com.bank.*");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return configProps;
    }

}

@Configuration
public class ConfigKafkaProducer {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, TransferNotification> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(properties());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, TransferNotification> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    private Map<String, Object> properties() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, "true");
        return configProps;
    }

}
```

**Listeners:**

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.transfer.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.transfer.email.group}")
@RetryableTopic(attempts = "${kafka.producer.retries}", backoff = @Backoff(30000L))

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.transfer.topic.dlt}", groupId = "${kafka.transfer.email.group}")

@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.transfer.topic}", groupId = "${kafka.transfer.log.group}")
```

Does anyone have any insights on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: If your Spring app is running as a container, 127.0.0.1 points at itself, not the variable that you've set `KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT: kafka:29092` but are not using. Also, your properties are not correct for using Spring Boot with Kafka https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/messaging.html#messaging.kafka

Comment: I thought that KAFKA_BROKERCONNECT would override the bootstrap-servers value. But you're right, replacing "127.0.0.1:9092" with "kafka:29092" worked. Thanks!

Comment: The spring boot documentation explains how to use externalized configuration like this